# How to calculate time in shell script when performing multiple operations in one line

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run one bash file (script.sh file) which will print some logs and i am redirecting logs in some text file.

I want to know how much time script.sh file will take to run?
I am redirecting logs like this:

```
./script.sh >> logs.txt
```

I am calculating time like this:

```
time ./scripts.sh
```

Can I do both operations (redirecting script.sh logs to text file and calculating time of the script execution in the same command OR in one line)?

Comment: why not run `time ./scripts.sh  >> logs.txt` ?

Comment: Also note: `time` writes to `stderr`, so redirection of stdout is not affected and the output of time would still appear on the console.

Comment: Did you not try it?

Answer (score 0):

If your script might also send relevant messages about errors into the log, but you do not want your time data in the log as well, then you will need to control the I/O for each separately.

Assume a file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo channel 1     # stdout
echo channel 2 >&2 # stderr
```

To get time info to the console but error logging to your file, wrap the I/O control in braces or a subshell.

With braces, you'll need a semicolon or to put the closing brace on the next line

```
$: time { ./tst >x 2>&1; }
```

With parens for a subshell you can include or leave it off.

```
$: time ( ./tst >x 2>&1 )
```

Either will show time info to the console:

```
real    0m0.154s
user    0m0.062s
sys     0m0.062s
```

The log will still have both.

```
$: cat x
channel 1
channel 2
```